# Change from formatted stream I/O to direct I/O in c

Tags: c, io

I want to be able to change this code to use direct I/O to write out the file, rather than formatted stream I/O? However I'm not really sure how to do this, help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 100
#define FORMATREAD "%12s %100s %100s"

int main(void) 
{
    FILE *in_ptr, *out_ptr;
    char fname[MAX], lname[MAX], number [12];

    in_ptr  = fopen("phonelist.txt", "r");
    out_ptr = fopen("history.txt", "w+");

    if ((NULL == in_ptr) || (NULL == out_ptr)) 
    {
        fputs("Problem opening files , exiting!", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (3 = fscanf(in_ptr , FORMATREAD , number , fname ,lname)) 
    {
        fprintf(out_ptr , "%s %s %s\n", number , fname , lname);
        printf("%s %s %s\n", number , fname , lname);
        printf("The phone book has format: phone number name\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        fprintf(*out_ptr , "Unknown type\n");
        printf("The phone book has unknown format\n");
    }
    fclose(in_ptr);
    fclose(*out_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new to coding so sorry if there are any blatant errors.

Comment: You don't indent your code at all, it's unreadable. Also wrong `FORMATREAD` if the array can hold `N` then it has to be `"%(N - 1)s"`  because of the `nul` terminator. And you are using the ugly Yoda condition but it still is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try and edit it so it's at least somewhat readable

Comment: By "direct" I/O do you mean the `write()` syscall?  And are you looking to retain the same output format (for some imagined performance benefit, perhaps) or to change to a more compact, machine-readable-only form?

Comment: @Joe as @JohnBollinger said, your code is good, almost very good except for the `FORMATREAD` and `(3 = fscanf(...))` is it compiling that way?

Comment: as @iharob said, using `3 = ...` and not `3 == ...` is an error not a warning. Typo?

Comment: You could use `fputs()` and and `fputc()` instead of `fprintf()` if that is what you mean by "unformatted".

Comment: Sorry looks like a typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @iharob : I'm looking it to change to more of a machine-readable-only form.

Comment: I would call that "more" formatted not "less"!

Comment: The thing is, you are writing character data.  You're not going to end up with a different output format without performing some kind of compression, which is probably not what you want.  (The situation would be different if some of your data were numeric, e.g. `int`s, `float`s, etc..)  I guess I still don't understand what you're really after.

Comment: @iharob Thanks for the advice, could you please further explain what you mean about the FORMATREAD. What exactly should I change to fix it, thanks?

Comment: It's that strings in c require an aditional character which you are not acounting for so the correct `FORMATREAD` is `"%11s%99s%99s"`. Also, adding explicit white spaces is not need in this case, but that is not a problem, the length modifiers are.

Answer (score 0):

To not use formatted output like `fprintf()`, construct the string in memory with `sprintf()` or other various methods and write that.  Important to insure that `buffer` is sufficiently large.

```
// fprintf(out_ptr , "%s %s %s\n", number , fname , lname);

// slightly oversize buffer, but it scales as the %s format and variables do.    
char buffer[sizeof number + sizeof fname + sizeof lname + sizeof FORMATREAD];
sprintf(buffer, "%s %s %s\n", number , fname , lname);
fputs(buffer, out_ptr);
```

---

Concern exists about  `fscanf(in_ptr , FORMATREAD , number , fname ,lname)` which implies *line* formatted data.  `FORMATREAD` does *not* detect `'\n'` as any different than `' '`.  Recommend to use `fgets()` to read the line of data and then parse it.

---

Code also needs to rectify buffer sizes and input format

```
#define MAX 100
#define FORMATREAD "%12s %100s %100s"
...
char fname[MAX+1], lname[MAX+1], number[12+1];
```

Good that code is checking the retrun value from input functions, but needs to use `==` rather than `=`  @Weather Vane

```
// if (3 = fscanf(in_ptr , FORMATREAD , number , fname ,lname)) 
if (3 == fscanf(in_ptr , FORMATREAD , number , fname ,lname))
```